# how to get specific element inside <li> element when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that will `console.log` the `innerHTML` of the list element that is clicked, it works perfectly

But I wanted to only `console.log` the `innerHTML` of the span element with class "x" that is inside the list

how can I do this?

```js
function myfunction() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll("#ol li"),
    array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    array.push(items[i].innerHTML);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = function() {
      console.log(this.innerHTML)
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<ol id="ol">
  <li>
    <span class="x">hello</span>
    <span class="xx">testing</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="x">hello2</span>
    <span class="xx">testing2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="x">hello3</span>
    <span class="xx">testing4</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="x">hello4</span>
    <span class="xx">testing4</span>
  </li>
</ol>

<button onclick="myfunction()">click</button>
```

Comment: what you have asked in question is already happening in your code, what else you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than placing a listener on each `li`, you can take advantage of [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), placing a single handler on the `ol`:

```html
<ol id="ol">
  <li>
    <span class="x">hello</span>
    <span class="xx">testing</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="x">hello2</span>
    <span class="xx">testing2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="x">hello3</span>
    <span class="xx">testing4</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="x">hello4</span>
    <span class="xx">testing4</span>
  </li>
</ol>

<button id="button">click</button>
```

```js
'use strict';

const button = document.querySelector('#button');

const findLI = el => {
  if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {
    return el;
  }
  
  return findLI(el.parentElement);
};

const registerItemsClickHandler = () => {
  const ol = document.querySelector('#ol');
  
  ol.onclick = event => {
    const li = findLI(event.target);
    console.log(li.innerHTML);
  };
};

button.onclick = registerItemsClickHandler;
```

Notice that we only register a single click handler (on the `ol`) and that we can use `event.target` to determine the specific element onto which the event was dispatched. It's also worth noting that a child any depth of the tree can be a dispatch target, so we can use the recursive `findLI()` function to find the first parent that is an `li`, if `el` itself isn't one.